# AngularJS exceptions during app loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception

I'm getting the following exceptions and I have no clue why

```
Exception #1
Uncaught ReferenceError: $window is not defined directives.js:746
(anonymous function) directives.js:746
```

The directive is very simple:

```
App.directive('diName', ['$window', function($window) {...}])

   Exception #2
    Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/ng/areq?p0=AppCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
            at Error (<anonymous>)
            at bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:6:447
            at bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:18:250)
            at bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:18:337)
            at bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:62:72
            at bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:49:117
            at p bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:361)
            at B bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:48:492)
            at h bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:43:24)
            at h bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:43:41) angular.js:9101
        (anonymous function) angular.js:9101
        (anonymous function) angular.js:6706
        g.$apply angular.js:11678
        (anonymous function) angular.js:1285
        d angular.js:3616
        Xb.c angular.js:1283
        Xb angular.js:1297
        xhrCallback home:10


        Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/ng/btstrpd?p0=document MINERR_ASSET:20
```

Doing manual bootstrap as follows:

```
<script>
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
      function xhrCallback() {

        <some XHR Processing Here>

        angular.module('App', []).value('X', <X-value>);
        angular.module('App', []).value('Y', <Y-value>);

        angular.bootstrap(document, ['App']);
      };

      <XHR request here>

    });
</script>
```

NOTE:  sometimes the app loads fine...so seems like some timing issue?

Comment: when first declare `module` need the second argument for dependencies. After it is declared, only use first argument to create refernce for adding directive, valu , factory etc

Comment: The app module is already defined in my app.js:
var App = angular.module('App', [
  'App.controllers',
  'App.filters',
  'App.services',
  'App.directives'
]);

Comment: I have changed the app to not use manual bootstrapping and to, instead, make better use of service/promises to pre-load application data.  This has fixed/removed the exceptions.  For what is worth, I do not think the fact that I was doing manual bootstrapping was the issue but rather perhaps the async pre-loading of all required initial page data for the multiple controllers at play when the app first loads up.  Was able to implement multiple services, some having async dependencies on others, to satisfy the controller/page data.

Comment: The issue with the first exception was missing quotes...arrghhh